# Incomplete chunks on Heroku with Dart app

Tags: heroku, websocket, dart

I enabled WebSockets support on my Heroku application but last week Heroku updated their platform's routing architecture.

Now I get incomplete chunks in my browser. You can try my app:
http://dartlangfr-risk.herokuapp.com

Here my server code:
https://github.com/ggirou/risk/blob/master/bin/main.dart#L16-L40

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks

Comment: In Chrome I see the error `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` for `/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js` and `index.html_bootstrap.dart.js`.